# Extension functions and classpaths

Tags: java, xslt, classpath, saxon

I am aware that this is a rather long and detailed post. I would have made it shorter and simpler if I could. I'd be grateful for any advice or ideas.

**Background**

I am writing XSLT to transfer data between two applications - call them Source and Target.
My XSLT is called by an integration engine supplied by the supplier of the Source System - call them Source Co.

The integration engine updates the Target by calling an adapter included in the engine that wraps an API written by the supplier of the Target system - call them Target Co. This all runs inside a J2EE server.

When the integration engine is deployed to the Java EE server it copies the JAR file implementing the Target System API so that it will be on the engine's classpath.

**My situation**

Source Co's Adapter that wraps Target CO's API only exposes a sub-set of the API. At times, my customers' business requirements can only be met by side-stepping the Source Co Adapter and calling the API directly from JAVA.

I have achieved this already by:

- Writing Java classes that accept and return DOM documents and call the API
- Deploying them as JARs into the Java EE engine so that they will be on the classpath visible to the integration engine and hence my XSLT
- In my XSLT I point at the Java class by declaring a namespace and then call the appropriate public static method via that namespace

This all works well. However...

**My Problem**

Recent versions of Target Co's API have:

- Removed several deprecated methods
- Exposed access to additional business entities in the Target system

Source Co's adapter uses these removed methods and therefore it needs to have an old version of the Target Co API on its classpath.

A customer's latest business requirements can only be met by using the latest API to access these additional business entities.

**My question**

How can I have the latest version of the API on the classpath of my extension function without it being on the classpath for the integration engine's adapter?

I could use custom class loaders of course. I've done this to load a 3rd party database driver jar that would have also broken the integration engine if it had been on its classpath. In the database driver case, this involves just using the custom classloader once. In the current case, however, I can't see how I can avoid having many, many calls to the classloader littered all over my code and this feels very wrong.

**Some technical details**

Source System - SAP

Target System - Oracle's Primavera

Java EE Engine - Netweaver 7.2

XSLT Processor - Saxon

Comment: In terms of detail, I'm out of my depth, but people tell me that the way to have multiple versions of the same component in different parts of the application is to use OSGi.

Comment: @Michael  - Thanks anyway. Thinking on this some more I don't think that I have any choice other than going the custom class loader route. Everything runs in the same JVM and there's nowhere I can intervene except maybe calling out to the shell - and that would stink worse than a custom class loader. I'll focus on how to factor this approach cleanly. BTW: I bought your book recently so that I could stop asking dumb questions on Stackoverflow. It is very, very good - thank you. I hate to think how many thousands of hours it took to write.